# There are no actions associated with the resource

Tags: liferay, portlet

I'm following Liferay In Action instruction to build a portlet using Service Builder and I'm new to it. I've added addProduct method. You can see the code below:

```java
public PRProduct addProduct(
        long companyID, long groupID, String productName,
        String serialNumber, long userID)
    throws SystemException, PortalException{

        PRProduct product = prProductPersistence.create(
            counterLocalService.increment(PRProduct.class.getName()));      

        resourceLocalService.addResources(
            companyID, groupID, userID, PRProduct.class.getName(),
            product.getPrimaryKey(), false, true, true);

        product.setProductName(productName);
        product.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
        product.setCompanyId(companyID);
        product.setGroupId(groupID);

        return prProductPersistence.update(product, false);
}
```

When I call this method from my portlet class I get "There are no actions associated with the resource com.inkwell.internet.productregistration.model.PRProduct". I don't understand what does it say and I don't know how to solve it. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is `resourceLocalService.addResources(....)`. You need only add your `PRProduct` as a resource if you are using [Liferay's Permission System](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+Liferay%27s+Permission+System+from+a+portlet).

Comment: As an added note, if you read the wiki linked, you'll see what the "actions" are.

Comment: Solved the problem. I had placed portlet.properties file in the wrong place.

Comment: @Beginner Where did you place that file? I'm facing the same issue but without the book and I don't have a portlet.properties file.